# How can I automatically set a customer code autoincremented for customer account?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have to work on Odoo for my job. It's my first time on it so there are some things I don't understand.

My specific mission is to ensure that when a quotation is confirmed: if the customer doesn't already have a customer code, he'll get the next.

For example, if the biggest customer code is "CL2000", I want that the next one to be "CL2001".

I have tried to create automatic actions with implemented tools in Odoo. I have managed to associate a customer code when a quotation is confirmed but always the same.

I didn't see a lot of tutorials on Odoo. If someone can help me to solve my problem or have a link to a good tutorial I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

For automatically set a customer code auto incremented for the costomer account you can create "ir.sequence" which is the odoo base feature.

Steps to create "ir.sequence" to Automatically generate customer code:

**Step 1:** Create a data file for sequence like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
   <data noupdate="1">     
     <!-- Sequences for customer codes --> 
    <record id="seq_res_partner" model="ir.sequence">
        <field name="name">Customer code</field>
        <field name="code">res.partner.customer.code</field>
        <field name="padding">8</field>
        <field name="number_next">CL2001</field>
        <field name="number_increment">1</field>
    </record>       
  </data>
</odoo>
```

**Step 2:** Inherit create the method of res.partner model to auto-generate customer code.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):             
    if isinstance(vals, dict):
        if not vals.get('ref', False):
            while 1:
                ref = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('res.partner.customer.code') or ''                    
                partner = self.env['res.partner'].search([('ref', '=', ref)])
                if not partner:
                    break
            vals.update({'ref': ref})
        elif vals.get('ref',False):
            ref_by_user = vals.get('ref',False) 
            partner = self.env['res.partner'].search([('ref', '=ilike', ref_by_user)])
            if partner:
                raise ValidationError('Internal Reference duplicate Error. \n This Internal reference already exist for Partner %s'%(partner[0].name))
        res = super(ResPartner, self).create(vals)           
    return res
```

According to the above steps, you can generate Customer code automatically.

I hope this will helps you. Thank you.